# Scala Play - How to convert a list of Scala Strings into an Array of javascript Strings (avoiding the &quot; issue)?

Tags: javascript, scala, playframework-2.0

When converting a Scala list of Strings into a javascript Array of Strings with the Play template engine, you probably start with something like this ...

```
var strArray = [@scalaListOfStrings.mkString(",")];
```

... and will find out that this is not working, because the quotes around the strings are missing. Next you might try something like this ...

```
var strArray = [@scalaListOfStrings.map(s => "\"" + s + "\"").mkString(",")];
```

... only to find out that this will wrap the strings in `&quot;` and not `"`. The only way I was able to make this work was with ...

```
var strArray = [@Html(scalaListOfStrings.map(s => "\"" + s + "\"").mkString(","))];
```

... and my question is: Is this the best/only way to do this?

Answer (score 5):

You can rely on the Json.toJson() method to make the conversion

```
@import play.api.libs.json._

var strArray = @Json.stringify(Json.toJson(List("hello", "world", "everybody")))
```

Answer (score 3):

Don't forget @Html.

```
@Html(Json.stringtify(Json.toJson(Scala object)))
```

Comment: `stringtify` or `stringify`? what imports are you using?? sorry to draw the attention, i was just passing through, trying to make some things works, and this code doesn't work in scala play 2.2.2. BTW: the Html has to be imported?